# How to stop component rendering till i get data back from API. For making asynchronous API call i am using react redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am calling my asynchronous action in ComponentDidMount. Now i want my component should not render till my data gets back from Api.
I am using redux saga as a middleware in react-redux application.

Comment: Simple check for some condition and don't render until u have data. This is called as conditional rendering.  https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use redux-sage-routines so that you have three stages in every api call or action, you can say. The request, success and failure respectively.
You can use variable such as has_loaded,error_loading in your state and update them in request,success and failure stages.
In your react component use conditional rendering to render your component by using these states. Add loaders or spinners till you get a response from the api.